# How to disable a rich:inputNumberSpinner with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, richfaces

In a form Im trying to control components using `javascript`. But the `rich:iputNumberSpinner` component can not be disabled or enabled with javascript.

Here is an example of my case:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function typeChange(){
    var element=document.getElementById("form2:hour");
    var element2=document.getElementById("form2:check");
if(document.getElementById("form2:type").value==1){
    element.disabled=true;
    element2.disabled=true;
    }
else{
    element.disabled=false;
    element2.disabled=false;
    }

}
</SCRIPT>

        <h:selectOneMenu id="type" onchange="typeChange()">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <rich:inputNumberSpinner id="hour" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" />
```

Waiting for your help

Comment: You can always use `f:ajax` on the `selectOneMenu` to re-render the spinner and evaluate it's `disabled` attribute with EL: `disabled="#{bean.typeValue == 1}"`. I'm sure there's a client-only alternative but I can't find it right now.

Comment: @mabi I want to use client side cotrol.

Comment: You can set the step increment to zero, but as @mabi says, there's the `disabled` attribute. You need to send data to the server anyway, otherwise the `onchange` event won't fire.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no public API for this, but based on inputNumberSpinner.js code, it can be disabled like this:

Disable:

```
var component = RichFaces.$('id');

if (!component.input.attr('disabled')) {
    component.input.attr('disabled', true);
    component.originalIncrease = component.increase;
    component.increase = function() {}
    component.originalDecrease = component.decrease;
    component.decrease = function() {}
}
```

Enable:

```
var component = RichFaces.$('id');
component.input.attr('disabled', false);
if (component.originalIncrease) {
    component.increase = component.originalIncrease;
    component.originalIncrease = null;
}
if (component.originalDecrease) {
    component.decrease = component.originalDecrease;
    component.originalDecrease = null;
}
```